# Can the code written in visual studio for mobile development could be executed in xcode MAC?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm planning to develop a mobile application using Xamarin for iOS and android in visual studio 2015. Could i compile and run the code written in visual studio, in Xcode MAC.

Answer (score 0):

The same code can be viewed and debugged on Mac with Xamarin Studio, not Xcode.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/